# trace() not written to flashlog.txt

Tags: macos, terminal, mxmlc

I'm using mxmlc on a Mac terminal to compile an AS 3.0 project and then I run it by opening the Main.swf in Flash Debugger 10.
Now, errors get written to the flashlog.txt just fine but my trace statements don't : (
I have mm.cfg in /Library/Application Support/Macromedia and it contains the following lines:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

What am I missing? Why is trace() not written to flashlog.txt?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler option "-debug=true" does the job. Like this:

mxmlc -use-network=false -default-background-color=#FFF00F -default-size=760,610 -debug=true Main.as