# How to check values of variables in actionscript with Flex SDK?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging, actionscript, trace

I use Flex SDK in command line to develop a flash.
But trace() doesn't work with Flex SDK.
Is there another good way to check values of variables?

Comment: if you have the debug player, trace does work, just with the command line it's not outputting anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to get a debug version of Flash and set up [mm.cfg](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/26/debugging-flex-applications-with-mmcfg-and-flashlogtxt/).

(You may need to swap `C:\Documents and Settings` with `C:\Users`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I tried that but that didn't work.
But after a few hours struggle,
i found the debug compile option is missing. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753649 )
I can trace variables now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to get Firefox, install debug version of Flash Player and install Firebug add-on. In Firebug console you can see the output and traces of your flash app.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your way but sadly Firebug console doesn't show trace from my flash app. Maybe because I use Mac.