# Flashplayer flashlog not being written to

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trace() not written to flashlog.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753649/trace-not-written-to-flashlog-txt)

I am trying to log flash trace messages in flashlog.txt in a win XP Pro SP3 system using flashplayer10_3r183_11_win_sa_debug.exe and flashplayer10_3r183_11_win_sa.exe.  I created the mm.cfg with the following settings:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
TraceOutputFileName=1
TraceOutputFileName=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data \Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\flashlog.txt
MaxWarnings=1000
```

However, I don't see anything being logged into the flashlog.txt file. Is there some error in my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed to the following in the new Flash Player and it worked
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1